# How can I solve the following equation?

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

The equation is given as follow

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{d} + \frac{1}{{d + 0.05}} + \frac{1}{{d + 0.1}} + \frac{1}{{d + 2}} = \frac{1}{{d + 0.5}} + \frac{1}{{d + 1}}
\end{equation}
$$
I think there are some tricks here to solve the equation.

**P.S.**

The equation can be rewritten as follow, and I got the results by MATHEMATICA:
$$
\begin{equation}
{d^5} + 3.325{d^4} + 4.225{d^3} + 1.83625{d^2} + 0.1525d + 0.0025 = 0
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{d_1} =  - 0.021865626127343277\\
{d_2} =  - 0.07967333686717089\\
{d_3} =  - 0.6398203720969836\\
{d_4} =  - 1.2918203324542512 + i0.7576841681889086\\
{d_5} =  - 1.2918203324542512 - i0.7576841681889086
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: In general quintic equations cannot be solved algebraically, so I wouldn't necessarily expect that it's possible to find a nice algebraic solution.

Comment: The mathematica solution to me hints that there are no clever tricks to find the solutions. This seems to be a generic quintic and the solutions don't seem to have any special structure that one could exploit.

Answer (score 2):

I would multiply the whole equation by $$d(d+\frac{1}{20})(d+\frac{1}{10})(d+2)(d+\frac{1}{2})(d+1)$$
After that i get $$800\,{d}^{5}+2660\,{d}^{4}+3380\,{d}^{3}+1469\,{d}^{2}+122\,d+2=0$$
Then you will need a numerical method!